# Why accessing Django QuerySet became very slow?

Tags: python, django

I have a model query in Django:

```
Query = Details.objects.filter(name__iexact=nameSelected)
```

I filter it later:

```
Query2 = Query .filter(title__iexact=title0)
```

Then I access it using:

```
...Query2[0][0]...
```

A few days ago it worked very fast. But now it became at least 20 times slower.
I test it on other PC, it works very fast.

Update: filtering is not the reason of the delay, Query[0][0] is the reason.
Besides that, it became super slow suddenly not over time.

What can make it so slow on my first PC?

Comment: Has your database grown large or was it same on both case?

Comment: filtering on the name will grow linear with the number of records (unless you have some sort of indexing mechanism).

Comment: Queryset size is the same. @Pax

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem filtering is not the reason of the delay, Query[0][0] is the reason

Comment: @Nessi: `QuerySet`s are lazy, so that means that `Query2` is *not* performed on the database, only when you force evaluation (for example with `Query2[0]` it will evaluate it at the database. So `Query2` indeed can not be the reason of the delay, since it does not result in a roundtrip to the db.

Comment: ohh, yes you are right. How can I fix it? make Queryset faster? in case of Query2[0]? @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to avoid loop for filtering the query. What I did is to create a hashmap dictionary

```
dict0 = {}
```

Then I added list of items and data that corresponds to that item in the query:

```
dict0 = dict(zip(title0List, DataList))
```

Finally I use dict0 instead of query, It boosts the speed at least 10 times for me)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to make a list out of the Queryset when you create it so that you have a real list not only a lazy QS

```
Query2 = list(Query .filter(title__iexact=title0))
```

Comment: yes this is smart, I will try it... and let you know

Comment: the same, unfortunately. It depends on db table, so strange...

Comment: Yes, it sounds very strange! Let us now when you got a solution...